# Using user input from TextInput - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to do some simple math in a kivy app using `TextInput` to allow users to input values. I defined the `TextInput` in the kv section of the code. I am unsure how to create a simple submit button to assign what's in the `TextInput` (which is defined in kv) to a variable so that I can do basic math with it in the python section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like the following:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: ti
    Button:
        text: 'do something!'
        on_press: run_some_function_with_text(ti.text)
```

`run_some_function_with_text` would probably most usefully be a method of some other widget, but could be anything else you like, or you could just write the function inline if it's simple.